# How can I create and trigger a simple onclick JS function in Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iife

How can I get an onclick function to trigger in a Rails 7 view?

I added a simple function:

```
// app/javascript/application.js
function myTest(myVar){
    alert(myVar);
};

myTest("test1");
```

The alert for "test1" does trigger on page load. However, I want to trigger this in an HTML onclick attribute within my view:

```
// my view
<a href="#" onclick="myTest('test2');">test</a>
```

However, the browser console says that the `myTest` function is not defined. I do see that the function ends up in my application.js file that the browser is loading.

```
// compiled application.js from asset pipeline
(() => {
  // ... all of the other rails JS here

  function myTest(myVar) {
    alert(myVar);
  }
  myTest("test1");
})();
```

Shouldn't I be able to trigger this directly from the console also? This also gives me the error that the function does not exist.

```
myTest("test3");
```

edit: I think all of the code in Rails is being put into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which is purposely not loaded in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a function to the window object using something like

```
window.myTest = function myTest(myVar) {
  alert(myVar);
};
```

This should make it available in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure there is a "rails way" to do this, but this solves my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to your element:

```
<a href="#" id="test-link">test</a>
```

On your javascript file:

```
document.querySelector("#test-link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert("test")
})
```